# How to stop derivative evaluation?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

It is posible to stop derivative evaulation in an expression?

Given

```
A = f[x]g[x];
F = W[t, n] /. W[x_, n_] -> D[A, {x, n}]
```

I would like `F` to be PartD(t, n)(f(t)g(t))  with the derivative not calculated, and when I evaluate

```
F /. n -> 0
```

I would like to get the general partial derivative

> ```
> f[t]g[t]
> ```

P.S. Sorry for language mistakes.

Comment: Could just do the usual Leibniz rule: `Sum[Binomial[n, k] Derivative[n - k][f][t] Derivative[k][g][t], {k, 0, n}]`

Comment: A=f[x]*g[x]  is simple example. For general case i dont know how A  look like.

Comment: So you want something like `Inactive[D][A, {x, n}]`?

Comment: Thanks ... maybe it will help.